# How to test a handler containing setState

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component `ButtonTest.js`

```
import React from 'react';
class ButtonTest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          First Button
        </button>
        <button disabled={this.state.disabled}>
          Second Button
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonTest;
```

Testing code in file `ButtonTest.test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ButtonTest from "./ButtonTest";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('<Button />', () => {
  it('test buttontest', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonTest />);
    const firstButton = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
    const secondButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1); 

    firstButton.props().onClick();
    expect(secondButton.props().disabled).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

`firstButton.props().onClick();` will trigger `handleClick`, then `setState` is called. But, `setState` is an async function, so the assertion will be called before `render`. That why the test is FAIL.

How to ensure the `render` finished before the assertion is called

Answer (score 0):

I update test code like this. I don't define secondButton at the beginning, I define it after clicking finished

```
describe('<Button />', () => {
  it('test buttontest', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonTest />);
    const firstButton = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
    firstButton.props().onClick();
    const secondButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1);

    expect(secondButton.props().disabled).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```